# How to raise the kendotreeviewchekbox clicked events checked/unchecked?

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui

In my project i have two kendogrids and one kendochart,one kendotreeview.
While checked treeview checkbox based on selected checkedbox graph & grid value  have to be change. how to write the code for that?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, you want listen treeview [check](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/treeview#events-check) events? Kendo UI Treeview check event is triggered after the user has checked or unchecked a checkbox.